# google collections ordering on map values

Tags: google-maps, collections

I would like to order a map(A,Double) based on the values.

```
Function<Map.Entry<A, Double>, Double> getSimFunction = new Function<Map.Entry<A, Double>, Double>() {
        public Double apply(Map.Entry<A, Double> entry) {
            return entry.getValue();
        }
    };

    final Ordering<Map.Entry<A, Double>> entryOrdering = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(getSimFunction);
    ImmutableSortedMap.orderedBy(entryOrdering).putAll(....).build();
```

How can I create a new sortedMap based on the ordering results or a sortedset based on the map.keyset()?

Comment: Would love to see the answer to this!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
ImmutableMap.Builder<A, Double> builder = ImmutableMap.builder();
for (Map.Entry<A, Double> entry : entryOrdering.sortedCopy(unsortedMap.entrySet())) {
    builder.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
ImmutableMap<A,Double> sortedMap = builder.build();
```